# Laravel 5.4 MethodNotAllowedHttpException error when enter wrong password after clearing cache

Tags: php, laravel

I have login form with two text fields email, password.when I tried to login with credentails it's working fine but when clear cache and then tried to login it gives the 'MethodNotAllowedHttp' exception.I am not getting the issue why it's showing this error. My code is as follows:

```
   Route::post('users/login/5', 'administrator\usersController@login')->name('sl'); 


    usersController.php
    namespace App\Http\Controllers\administrator;
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
    use Illuminate\Validation\Validator;
    use Session;

    class FreeusersController extends Controller {

        function login(Request $request) {
            $type = $request->segment(3);

            //print_r($request);
            echo "type=".$type; 
            echo $request->input('email');
            echo $request->input('password');

            die("sss");

            if ($request->isMethod('post') && !empty($type)) {
                $this->validate($request, [
                    'email' => 'required|min:5,max:50',
                    'password' => 'required|min:5,max:50'
                ]);
                switch ($type) {
                    case 5:
                        $condArr = ['email' => $request->input('email'), 'password' => $request->input('password'), 'type' => '5', 'role' => 'father'];
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        $condArr = ['email' => $request->input('email'), 'password' => $request->input('password'), 'type' => '4', 'status' => true];
                        break;
                }

                if (Auth::attempt($condArr)) {
                    return redirect('administrator/dashboard');
                } else {
                    return redirect(url()->previous())->withErrors(['password' => 'Invalid credentials'])->withInput();
                }

            } else {
                return redirect("/");
            }
        }
    }

<form action="/users/login/5" id="login-form" method="post" class="smart-form client-form">

    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <fieldset>
        <section>
            <label class="label">Email</label>
            <label class="input"> <i class="icon-append fa fa-user"></i>
                <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}">
        </section>
        <section>
            <label class="label">Password</label>
            <label class="input"> <i class="icon-append fa fa-lock"></i>
                <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control" name="password">
        </section>
    </fieldset>
    <footer>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
            LogIn
        </button>
    </footer>
</form>
```

Comment: post your `view` code

Comment: i have added view code

Answer (score 0):

You have to clear routes:

```
php artisan route:cache
```

Then it will remember that login action is post.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are getting this error because you when you are calling this url there is another url with something like `users/{id}` which means anything after `users/`. May be you are using resource route. So, when you call url `users/login/5` its taking `login/5` as `$id` of that `users/{id}` url.

But that url is for `GET` method. You are calling this with post method, as a result you are getting this error.

**Solution**

You can try calling your url using route method like:

`action="{{route('sl', ['id'=>5])}}"`

If it doesn't work then you can change your route to something else. For example:

`Route::post('user/login/5', 'administrator\usersController@login')->name('sl');`

Here you can use `user` instead of `users` because you already have a url with a `users`. Don't forget to change your action too.

Answer (score 0):

First look at your routes with php artisan route:list.

Then are you sure of your request verb ? Look in your navigator console to look at your requests.